# create a new table from 2 other tables

Tags: pandas

If I want to merge the table with 2 other tables b,c 
where table a contains columns:( Parent, Style, Ending_Date, WeekNum, Net_Requirment)
tables and calculate how much is required to make product A in a certain date.

The table should like the BOM (Bill of Material)

Can it be applied by pandas?

table b represent the demand for product A per date:

```
Style  Date        WeekNum Quantity 
A      24/11/2019    0      600
A       01/12/2019    1      500
```

table c represent Details and quantity used to make product A:

```
Parent Child Q 
A       A1    2
A1      A11    3
A1      A12    2
```

so table a should be filled like this:

```
Parent  Child  Date        WeekNum  Net_Quantity
A        A1   24/11/2019    0         1200
A1       A11   24/11/2019    0         3600
A1       A12    24/11/2019   0         2400
A        A1     01/12/2019    1         1000
A1       A11    01/12/2019    1         3000
A1       A12     01/12/2019    1         2000
```

Comment: If I understood that correctly, you want to merge both DataFrames: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html
After merging them the Net_Quantity can be easily calculated as usual.

Comment: can you please us some code you did so far?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome, in order to properly merge these tables and the rest you would have to have a common key to merge on. What you could do is add said key to each table like this:

```
data2 = {'Parent':['A','A1','A1'], 'Child':['A1','A11','A12'], 
        'Q':[2,3,2], 'Style':['A','A','A']} 

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

After this you can do a left join on the first table and then you can have multiple rows for the same date. So essentially this:

(notice if you do a left join, your left table will create as many duplicate rows as needed tu suffice the matching key on the right table)

```
data = {'Style':['A','A'], 'Date':['24/11/2019', '01/12/2019'], 
        'WeekNum':[0,1], 'Quantity':[600,500]} 

df = pd.DataFrame(data) 

mergeDf = df.merge(df2,how='left', left_on='Style', right_on='Style')
mergeDf
```

Then to calculate:

```
test['Net_Quantity'] = test.Quantity*test.Q
test.drop(['Q'], axis = 1,inplace=True)
```

result:

```
    Style   Date    WeekNum Quantity    Parent  Child   Net_Quantity
0   A     24/11/2019    0   600            A    A1      1200
1   A     24/11/2019    0   600            A1   A11     1800
2   A     24/11/2019    0   600            A1   A12     1200
3   A     01/12/2019    1   500            A    A1      1000
4   A     01/12/2019    1   500            A1   A11     1500
5   A     01/12/2019    1   500            A1   A12     1000
```